# Error: too few Parameters. Expected 3...while executing SQL statement in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I've done this before, just a test as to whether a record already exists in a table before I insert a new record.  This was basically what I did, yet this time I get an error

```
Error: "3061 Too few parameters. Expected 2."
```

I tried to be very specific (`tblfromICPMS.Woid` instead of just `Woid`) thinking that might help, but it didn't really make a difference.  I get the specifically at the line

```
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
```

This is the code, where ThisWoid, Analyte and ThisTestId are local variables:

```
DIM rs As Object
strSQL = "SELECT tblfromICPMS.Woid, tblfromICPMS.Analyte, tblfromICPMS.TestID FROM tblFROMICPMS WHERE (tblFROMICPMS.woid = " & ThisWoid & ") AND (tblFROMICPMS.analyte = " & Analyte & ") AND (tblfromICPMS.Testid=" & ThisTestID & ") "
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
   "insert record"
End IF
```

**UPDATE:** error message changed to 1 expected after updating sqlstr in comments, also included declaration of rs.  For clarification tblFromICPMS is a table which contains the columns Woid, Analyte and TestId.  I have retrieved three values and stored them in local variables ThisWoid, Analyte and ThisTestId.  I want to insert a record but first I must see if it already exists in tblfromICPMS.  Also ThisWoid and Analyte are strings

Comment: Have you tried to debug? I am afraid, in what you posted here, you don't have a line that trows error. And what is this? `(tblFROMICPMS.woid = ThisWoid)`. What is `ThisWoid`. Isn't it supposed to be `(tblFROMICPMS.woid = " & ThisWoid  & ")"`?

Comment: Have a look at `TabelfromICPMS.TestID`. That should be `tblfromICPMS.TestID` instead.

Comment: Are you concatenating that sql string in the actual code?  If you step through, you will see the statement is literally `SELECT tblfromICPMS.Woid, tblfromICPMS.Analyte, TabelfromICPMS.TestID FROM tblFROMICPMS WHERE (tblFROMICPMS.woid = ThisWoid) AND (tblFROMICPMS.analyte = Analyte) AND (tblfromICPMS.Testid=ThisTestID) `  where you want something like "WHERE (tblFromICPMS.woid = " & strVariable & ") AND " `

Comment: Can you include the declaration for rs?

Comment: Basically, we all agree that you should try this string `"SELECT tblfromICPMS.Woid, tblfromICPMS.Analyte, tblfromICPMS.TestID FROM tblFROMICPMS WHERE (tblFROMICPMS.woid = " & ThisWoid & ") AND (tblFROMICPMS.analyte = " & Analyte & ") AND (tblfromICPMS.Testid=" & ThisTestID & ") "` And also, if any of your conditions are compared to string you need a single quote on each side as `"... ='" & var & "' and ..."`

Comment: Since ThisWoid is a string, I would write "...(tblFROMICPMS.woid = ' " & ThisWoid & " ')..." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd try DIMing the rs as a RecordSet, not an Object.  Also, stick in a Message Box just to make sure your SQL string makes sense:

```
DIM rs As Recordset
strSQL = "SELECT Woid, Analyte, TestID FROM tblFROMICPMS WHERE (woid = " & ThisWoid & ") AND (analyte = " & Analyte & ") AND (Testid=" & ThisTestID & ") "
msgbox strSQL
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
   "insert record"
End IF
```

See if the message box results give you any clues as to what's wrong.  Typically, that error happens when Access doesn't understand one of your variables.

Don't forget, **text** needs to be surrounded by single quotes in your SQL string, **integers** do not.